# Is there a way in QGIS to display vector files on a shared drive without others being able to edit the file?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, file-formats, layer-file, qlr

So just like lyr-files in ArcGIS.
I have read that qlr-files are QGIS answer to lyr. But as far as I can see when I try, the receiver can edit in the main source of the data through the qlr-file.
So basically I would like to display some files on a shared drive, where I am the only one who can manage the source in postgreSQL, geopackage or just shape.

Comment: Give everyone else "read only" rights to the folder the data is in. That's how it is done at our company.